# how to do this interpolation formula faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function of Everett interpolation and I'd like to make it a little bit faster than it is right now. It works very well b

x and y are the parameters: time and values.
xi is the time which I want to have interpolated value.

```
def everett(x,y,xi):
    '''
    function everett

    INPUT:
    x       list float      
    y       list float      
    xi      float           

    RETURN:
    yi      float


    '''
    n = len(x)       #interpolation degree

    h = x[1]-x[0]       #differences between epochs

    D = np.zeros([n,n+1])
    D[:,0] = x
    D[:,1] = y

    for j in range(1,n):                    #loop to each column
        for i in range(0,n-j):              #loop to cell within a column
            D[i,j+1] = D[i+1,j] - D[i,j]

    #Finding the value of u
    for i in range(0,n):
        u = ( xi - x[i] ) / h

        if u == 0:
            return y[i]
        elif( u > 0 and u < 1.0 ):
            break

    if i == n-1:
        return None

    z = i
    w = 1 - u
    i = 0
    yi = 0
    m1 = u
    m2 = w
    for j in range(1,n+1,2):
        yi += m1 * D[z+1-i,j] + m2 * D[z-i,j]

        i = i + 1
        m1 *= (u - i) * (u + i) / ((j+1)*(j+2))
        m2 *= (w - i) * (w + i) / ((j+1)*(j+2))

        if (z-i)<0 or (z+1-i)>(n-j-1):
            break   #//checks validity of index in the table

    return yi
```

Thx!

**EDIT: some modification using numpy**

I change this part of code:

```
#Finding the value of u
for i in range(0,n):
    u = ( xi - x[i] ) / h

    if u == 0:
        return y[i]
    elif( u > 0 and u < 1.0 ):
        break

if i == n-1:
    return None
```

by this one:

```
#Finding the value of u
u = (xi - x) /h
u0 = np.where(u == 0)[0]

if u0.size:
    return y[u0[0]]

i = np.where((u > 0) & (u < 1.0))[0]
if not i.size:
    return None

z = i[0]
u = u[z]
```

the biggest problem I have right now is how to modify the last loop and the first loop where variable `D` is filled with values.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is the absence of Numpy a design decision?

Comment: no, but I have no idea how to use numpy in this case.

Comment: looks like a perfect job for Cython.

Comment: While @Moritz 's suggestion of Cython is a good one I actually recommend you spend a few days getting to know Numpy. If you plan to do any serious numerical work in Python, you'll find it indispensable. Just some basic changes to your code using Numpy would simplify the code and give you orders of magnitude better performance.

Numpy is a numerical library based around the numpy.array() class which is a thin wrapper around a C-array. Calculations get pushed to binary blobs that operate on those arrays so you get C-like performance on your numerical operations.

Comment: totally agree with Timtro

Comment: So, I'm not very familiar with Everett's formula, but looking it up, it seems to be an expansion as a sum of powers of the central difference. Is that right? If that's the case, I think a re-write is in order because this should be a straightforward assembly and composition of arrays. Construct arrays with the central differences of appropriate order and arrays with the coefficients and combine them as in Everett's formula. Numpy or Scipy probably have facilities to computing central differences, but if not, I hint in my answer by showing the forward difference.

Answer (score 1):

Include [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), put the data into numpy.array()s and use numpy operations. You'll simplify your code and get, potentially, orders of magnitude better performance. If you're comfortable with Matlab, you'll find numpy easy to learn.

Loops like

```
for i in range(0,n):
    u = ( xi - x[i] ) / h
```

become simple one liners:

```
u = (xi - x) / h
```

(where x is an array, u will be an array and the `-` and `/` will do element-wise arithmetic if `xi` and `h` are numbers)

This even works for whole arrays. For example, a forward difference can be expressed in 1D as

```
Dx = X[1:] - x[:1]
```

The X[1:] means the elements of X excluding the first and X[:1] means the elements of X excluding the last.

You can do the same on N-dimensional arrays, eliminating nested loops.

I wrote this article a long time ago, but it's still relevant. You'll see where I use numpy to speed up a finite difference calculation on a mesh (solving the 2D diffusion equation) while also simplifying the code: http://www.timteatro.net/2010/10/29/performance-python-solving-the-2d-diffusion-equation-with-numpy/

If I get a chance, I will come back and help you work on your specific code. But actually, I think this algorithm is a perfect project to introduce yourself to numpy.

And, if you're more interested in the result than you are the method, [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) (an extension of numpy) has interpolation functions:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

Comment: Thanks @Timtro. I try to replace this part of code: `for i in range(0,n): u = ( xi - x[i] ) / h;
if u == 0: return y[i];
        elif( u > 0 and u < 1.0 ):
            break;
    if i == n-1:
        return None`
by this one: `y = np.array(y); x = np.array(x); 
    u = (xi - x) /h;
    u0 = np.where(u == 0)[0];
    if u0.size:
        return y[u0[0]];
    i = np.where((u > 0) & (u < 1.0))[0];
    if not i.size:
        return None`
but this approach slowed down my code... moreover I have completely  no idea how to solve the problem with the last loop and the array `D`...

Comment: @Grzegorz I'm happy to try to help, but I'm having a really hard time reading the unformatted Python code. It isn't surprising that importing numpy and just converting `x` and `y` to numpy arrays slowed things down, because now you've forced your element access to go through an extra layer of abstraction to get at the data. The speedup comes when you replace everything with numpy expressions/functions that operate on the np.arrays().